Why shouldn't the Israelites have been asleep when God gave the Torah?
On Shavuot eve, we have a custom of staying up all night to study Torah, to make amends because, when the Israelites were about to receive the Torah at dawn, they were sleeping, and God had to awaken them with thunder and lightning. The Midrash [Song of Songs Rabbah 1:12] even says that God taunted them through the mouth of Isaiah, saying:

Why is it that when I came, no man was there; when I called, no one was there to answer? [Is. 50:2]

This is not in the Torah.  The Torah [Ex. 19:16] only says it happened "בִּֽהְיֹ֣ת הַבֹּ֗קֶר -- When morning came into being", i.e. at dawn.  Why shouldn't the Israelites be sleeping as dawn breaks?

Isn't there something associated with much more potentially being motzi zera l'vatalah if they're asleep so they should have stayed awake, like the Kohein Gadol on Yom Kippur night?

@Yehuda אבן עזרא פירוש שני שמות י"ט:י"א
והיו נכונים – אולי לא יישן אדם מהם בלילה, ששמעו קול השם, כדרך כהן גדול ביום הכיפורים.
AND BE READY. Its meaning might be that no person among them should sleep during the night, after the manner of the high priest on Yom Kippur,⁠ as Israel would hear God's voice in the morning.

Why didn’t Hashem give the Torah before bedtime, so the Israelites could sleep on it?  Or after breakfast, so they would have full stomachs?  Or at midday, so they could see better?  All good questions.

Rabbi Yaakov Chaim Goldwicht z"l (אספת מערכות פרשת יתרו - sorry, no available link) has a lengthy and deep lecture to explain why they felt it important to sleep. Without delving into his words again, this is in short, and on a superficial level, the way I remember them. Any unclarity is my fault. The reason why they went to sleep was not due to an indifference to the forthcoming Revelation. On the contrary. They thought it was an essential preparation. Whilst awake, we can only achieve a limited amount of Torah knowledge, as our physicality acts as a wall between the spiritual world where the knowledge of תורה resides. That barrier disappears greatly whilst asleep, which is why all prophets, besides Mozes who was constantly on a high spiritual level, received their prophecies in a stage of sleep/trance. The knowledge attained whilst asleep can then be further developed upon awaking. In fact, many Torah giants throughout all generations, after they had toiled in Torah with all their might during the day, but were still left with unresolved questions, merited to a solution to their questions during the short sleep which they allowed themselves. To be sure, this only applies to people who use their awake hours to toil in Torah. Those who waste their days, will not become more knowledgeable whilst asleep. The Jewish people had travelled 49 days towards the giving of the Torah. During all that time they were preparing for that great Divine Revelation. However, they thought that they would be incapable to be grasp those high revelations whilst awake. Whilst their body was “dressed” on their soul. And indeed, when they eventually heard the first words of the ten commandments, they, in their physical state, couldn't cope with it. That is why they went to sleep. But they were wrong. The words of Torah can only be handed over with the full cooperation of the recipient and for that one has to be awake. What made them make that mistake? Here human nature comes to play. Perhaps, deep down, there was an element of laziness involved. By staying up Shavuos night we want to be repair that small element of laziness and thus merit to absorb the full measure of spirituality our soul is capable off.
